# BinaryWriter.Write is not creating the .pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, attachment, notificationservices

I am using this function to write a report into a pdf file and send it as an attachment in a email.

```
string strNovaQueryString = string.Empty;
string pathFile = "";

string[] fields;
string[] values;

fields = ParamRelatorio.Split('|');

foreach (string key in fields)
{
    string[] param= key.Split(new char[] { '=' });
    strNovaQueryString += param[0] + "=" + param[1] + "&";
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strNovaQueryString))
    strNovaQueryString = strNovaQueryString.TrimEnd('&');

string url = reportURL + "/ViewReport.aspx?" + strNovaQueryString;

string userName = user;
string password = pass;
string strPostData = String.Format("user={0}&pass={1}", userName, password);
byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPostData);

System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

System.IO.Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();
outputStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
outputStream.Close();

System.Net.HttpWebResponse rep = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream str = rep.GetResponseStream();
string contentType = rep.ContentType;

string fileType = "";

if (contentType != null)
{
    string[] splitString = contentType.Split(';');
    fileType = splitString[0];
}

if (fileType != null && fileType.ToLower() == "application/pdf")
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

    int bytesRead = str.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytesRead];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, buffer2, 0, bytesRead);

        pathFile = attPath+ "reportName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".pdf";

        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(pathFile, FileMode.Create));
        binaryWriter.Write(buffer2);
        binaryWriter.Close();

        bytesRead = str.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
    }

}
return pathFile;
```

It is saving a pdf file inside the path that I want (something like "C://Documents//Att"), but the pdf file is empty. 
The email is being sent but the pdf is empty. I think that `binaryWriter.Write(bytesRead);` is not working as expected, or the variable is empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `pathFile = attPath+ "reportName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".pdf";` where are you declaring the variable attPath?

Comment: Go look up `Stream.CopyTo`.  Also, lawd, dat code.

Comment: @bill, the variable attPath is comming as a parameter

Comment: Seems the problem is on each iteration of while loop you open a file and write to it from start. Try to open file before while loop and close after.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)` instead of `BinaryWriter`.  Its much simpler.  Check out the MSDN article here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You dont' call to Stream.Flush, but Close stream (Close doesn't  guarantee call to Flush)

And always use using(var stream=  ... ) - because you must ensure that file will be unblocked.